# Prove that co finite set over N is countable

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have $$ L = \{A \in \mathcal P(\mathbb N) | A \text{ co finite over } \mathbb N\}$$

How can I prove that $L$ is countable?

Thanks

Comment: I've edited your post to format the math in it. Please verify that it says what you intended.

Comment: Note there is a canonical bijection between the set of finite subsets, and the set of cofinite subsets.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** Find a bijection
$$\{ A \in \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N}) : A\ \text{cofinite} \} \longleftrightarrow \{ A \in \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N}) : A\ \text{finite} \}$$
and use familiar facts about countable sets to deduce that the latter, hence the former, is countable.